# Google Analytics (GA4) event data is different between reports and exploration

Tags: api, google-analytics-4

I am recently new with GA4 and I found that I get different data from reports and exploration for the same event.

For example I want to get the data:

- eventName: Load Result
- date: 2023-02-01

Event have 2 parameters:

- event_category
- event_label

Here is the data from reports and exploration. while exploration get a data bigger than reports. And when I use GA4 API to get data, I can only return the data same as reports.I guess maybe there is a sampling, but how can I get no sample data,I hope to know if there is a way to get the same data as exploration data by GA4 API.

reports data:

[reports data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPIvB.png)

exploration data:

[exploration data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD9P5.png)

API data:

[API data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1IHO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is one of the known GA4 bugs. General consensus and advise for now is to never use Reports. Always use explorer.

But even Explorer is, at times, pretty odd with certain combinations of dimensions and metrics, often conflicting with itself within the same tab.

For now, the best you can do to Firebase and GA4 data is to export it to BQ and then look at raw numbers. They look much better and seem to be quite significantly more reliable.

Comment: But if I use Google Analytics Data API(GA4), I return the  same result with Reports. If it's possible that I want to return the same results with explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides an article titled [[GA4] Data differences between reports and explorations](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9371379) that contains some possible reasons why the data looks differently between the reports.

If you are dealing with an issue related to sampling, read the section titled "Large amounts of data".